# SSH command for deleting files in a folder by name

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've got a folder with over 5000 files. All files names are numeric (ex: 132455.jpg) and would like to delete all files that have names below a certain number (for ex: delete all files with names that is than 15000)
What's the quickest and easiest way to do this?

PS: Sorry I'm a novice at this and this SSH business seems intimidating but need to clear out this directory quickly as it's way too clogged with files

Comment: Why would you need `ssh` ? Are you working on some remote server where those files needs to be removed ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Also, ftp isn't an option. with so many files in the directory it always timesout

Comment: Connect with `ssh` then delete them as you would otherwise. The command should be the same after connecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done in pure bash.

```
for f in *; do
#for every file in current directory
    if [[ ${f%.*} -lt $yourNumber ]]; then
    #if the current filename minus the extension is less than $yourNumber
        rm "$f"
        #remove the file
    fi
done
```

To do this over ssh we can `ssh yourUser@yourHost \"/cd dir/to/process; for f in *; do if [[ ${f%.*} -lt yourNumber ]]; then rm "$f"; fi; done\"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one could solve your problem :

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'find . -type f -name "15000.jpg" -exec rm -f {} \'
```

This one will run on your 192.168.1.1 server with your root account the following command between the simple quote .

This command will find all the file with the 15000.jpg name in the "." directory (you can specify your path to avoid to run this command on all your system), and the matches will be remove.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use putty to take an ssh connection, browse to the folder and type
    rm {0..14999}.jpg

that will remove all files lower than 15000.jpg